# ReactJS custom hook, called again depending on it's data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call a custom hook once again depending on it's value that returns.

Currently, I have this:

```
const { data } = useMaximumAmount();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (data?.MaxAmount < 1) {
    // do something
  }
}, [data?.MaxAmount]);
```

But also that hook it returns an "error" so I could call it like this way:

```
const { data, error } = useMaximumAmount();
```

Now if "error" is true, I need to call the `useMaximumAmount` again in order to retrieve `data` again. That `error` is true sometimes because inside `useMaximumAmount` there's an API call that could fail or not.

Any idea?

Or maybe it's better to edit the hook and detects that the API call gives an error and make the call again before returning it's response?

Comment: I would handle this case in the custom hook itself. So if there is an error, retry inside the hook and emit the new value as soon as you get it back from the API.
You can still emit the error prop to your component, i.e. for not rendering something in case there is an error. Simply unset the error value as soon as you get valid data from there API call

Comment: Yup, It's more easier to handle errror in your useMaximumAmount (setData state base on the response). If you dont want to pass data as props to your component. You can create a context and useContext for it.

Comment: thanks guys, so instead "call again the hook depending on its data response" it's a better approach to say "call the API again depending on its data response, and return what you really need"

Comment: "calling the hook again" is not something really possible with React hooks. They are called by render and they can't be called conditionally (e.g. on error). Though if it really needs to be managed by the calling component, the hook itself could expose a `retry()` function which could be called conditionally. The Apollo GraphQL client's hooks work like this.